# How to align the boostrap navbar to the center of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar using bootstrap

[image: The current appearance of the navbar]

I have created it using the following code snippet `(Here I'm using bootstrap version 3.3.5)`

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.someone.com/">Home</a>
            </div>    
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </nav>
</body>
```

But I wanted center this navbar to the center of the page like below

[image: The wanted result]

I need to know how to do this using additional `css` styling .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `margin: 0 auto;` to navbar class to center.

```css
.navbar {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://epidemicdash.epizy.com/">Home</a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://epidemicdash.epizy.com/">User</a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://epidemicdash.epizy.com/">About</a>
            </div>    
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </nav>
```

Comment: This one works good without the `body` part of the `css` , and gives the expected result .

Comment: I checked your code again, no need to add an additional div around navbar. Simply apply the styles to `.navbar` class and it will work.

Comment: Happy it worked, please mark as correct if it solved your problem. Thank you!

Comment: But bellow is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

Here I have added one class `navbar-content` to second line.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar-content">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.someone.com/">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Put bellow styles in your css file.

```
.navbar-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```